# framework7 wont open javascript link to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, anchor, html-framework-7

I have a button that activates the function clickEvent() onclick. I want a new anchorlink to open only if the condition is not met.

```
createClick() {
    if (condition) {
     //something
    } else {
    window.open("#about", "_self");
}
```

However, I can't get framework7 to open the link with my javascript. It only works if I add an href to the link, which is not what I want because then it wont be constrained by my conditions.

```
<button onclick="clickEvent();" href="#about" class="item-link button button-big button-fill color-orange">GO!</button>
```

I have already allowed access to href="*" in my config.xml so I don't think thats the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have 2 ways to do this:

## 1. Put your condition on the link:

So the link will not open untill condition is True.

```js
function createClick() {
  if (1==2) {
   return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="return createClick()">Go to Google</a>
```

## 2. If your target page is a framework7 template page, you can simply call:

```
mainView.router.loadPage(url)
```

Know more in Router API document page: http://framework7.io/docs/router-api.html

I hope this helps.